# Register custom types globally for Azure Automation Account and Runbooks

Tags: .net, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Is it somehow possible to register types from a module (.NET class library, dll) globally for my Azure Automation account, so the Powershell Runbooks don't have to use the `Add-Type` command in order to make use of the types?

A bit of background:

I'm trying to introduce proper datamodels to use as in- and outputs in my Azure Logic Apps and Runbooks. These models are defined in a .NET class library, and I successfully imported the library as a module. 
I can use the `Add-Type` command to use the types, but I can't figure out how to use the types as Powershell inputs, because the `Param` keyword has to be the first line of code in the script.

```
Param
(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [MyLibrary.MyDto] $dto # ... doesn't work, the MyDto type is unknown
)

Add-Type -Path "C:\Modules\User\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.dll" # How do I avoid having to do this in all my PS runbooks?

$response = New-Object -TypeName MyLibrary.MyResponse -ArgumentList "xxx" # ... this works just fine!

# ... more stuff to come
```

In the above sample, the instantiation of `MyResponse` works, but using `MyDto` as an input parameter doesn't as the type is unknown at that point.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible in the automation account currently.

If you want the feature, you could post it in the [automation feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation).